# Error deploying Java Springboot web application using Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile
> (default-compile) on project MurderMysteryCRUDWebApp: Fatal error
> compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
> !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
> We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
> please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.  !     Push failed

**Here is my POM.XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.javaguides</groupId>
    <artifactId>MurderMysteryCRUDWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MurderMysteryCRUDWebApp</name>
    <description>Murder Mystery log using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Getting the error at the top when trying to deploy Java Spring Boot application using `Heroku`. Not sure what else to try. I am using the git connect option on `Heroku`.

I've tried everything I could from Stackoverflow, I have exhausted my options please help me, thank you.

Comment: Can you put full pom and logs ....check if you have added java 8 in heroku or not

Comment: did you get this resolve? I'm facing the same issue.